# Puppet agent runs in POSIX locale in Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, locale, ubuntu-16.04, puppet

I set up a Puppet agent running on Ubuntu 16.04 deployed in AWS EC2. The Puppet agent service installation is done in the userdata.

I then tried to use it to install some monitoring agent, and I get the following error message when the agent is running through the service:

```
Could not evaluate: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

I made sure the default locale and the locale of the root user (that runs the agent) is en_US.utf8, both when logging in SSH and by adding logs to the puppet agent installation script running in the user data. I also added debug printout to the module that installs my monitoring agent, and it says current locale is POSIX.

When I try to run the agent not through the service (just "puppet agent -t" in SSH as root) - it works fine, and the logging I added shows the locale is en_US.utf8

How come the puppet agent runs under the POSIX locale and not under the en_US.utf8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolved.

Just needed to add the following to /etc/default/puppet:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=''
LC_ALL=''
```

BUT this doesn't work (at least to me) if you add it and just restart the service. Only worked when if the lines were there before the Puppet service is installed.